# Генерация proxy для wcf

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf

В vs есть замечательная функция-это приконектится к веб-службе и сгенерировать все необходимое.

Однако, что делать если служба и клиент в одном проекте ? Если запустить службу в дебаг, то студия запрещает что либо делать в обозревателе объектов.

Получается, что нужно разворачивать службу, в потом только генерить прокси в студии? Или запускать службу в дебоше, а потом консольной утилитой генерить прокси? Однако, вроде, она не генерит app.config

Comment: А почему не создать клиента руками, не используя автоген студии?

Comment: Debug -> Start Without Debugging ?

Comment: @kmv, хм... Не подумал про это. Спасибо.